Corollary 5.9 of Atiyah and Macdonald
This post is related to my recent answer. Now I think user bfhaha approach is correct, though I can’t rigioursly fill details. My first approach to show $\mathfrak{n}^c=\mathfrak{n}'^c=\mathfrak{m}$ was also same as his/her/their answer. For sake of completeness, I am adding relevant portion of that post here.

Corollary 5.9.
Let $A\subseteq B$ be rings,
$B$ integral over $A$;
let $\mathfrak{q}, \mathfrak{q}'$ be prime ideals of $B$ such that $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq\mathfrak{q}'$ and $\mathfrak{q}^c=\mathfrak{q}'^c=\mathfrak{p}$ say.
Then $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}'$.
Proof. By (5.6),
$B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is integral over $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the extension of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and let $\mathfrak{n}, \mathfrak{n}'$ be the extensions of $\mathfrak{q}, \mathfrak{q}'$ respectively in $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Then $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$;
$\mathfrak{n}\subseteq \mathfrak{n}'$,
and $\mathfrak{n}^c=\mathfrak{n}'^c=\mathfrak{m}$.
By (5.8) it follows that $\mathfrak{n}, \mathfrak{n}'$ are maximal,
hence $\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{n}'$,
hence by (3.11)(iv) $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{q}'$.

There is slight abuse of notation. We are using same contraction and extension notation for multiple different ring homomorphism: monomorphism $A\to B$ and $A_\mathfrak{p}\to B_\mathfrak{p}$, and natural homomorphism $A\to A_\mathfrak{p}$ and $B\to B_\mathfrak{p}$.
We want to show $\mathfrak{n}^c=\mathfrak{n}'^c=\mathfrak{m}$. One of the way is following:
$$\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{p}^e=(\mathfrak{q} \cap A)^e\subseteq \mathfrak{q}^e \cap A_\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{n}\cap A_\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{n}^c.$$
If we assume extension is taken place in $B\to B_\mathfrak{p}$ (otherwise proving $\subseteq$ is not obvious), then $\mathfrak{p}^e$ doesn’t make sense because $\mathfrak{p}$ may not be ideal of $B$. One might conclude $\subseteq$ by directly using (1.18), that is $(\mathfrak{q} \cap A)^e\subseteq \mathfrak{q}^e \cap A^e$. But $A$ is not ideal of $B$. It seems like we have to extend (no pun intended) our definition of extension of ideals to arbitrary set. Am I missing something obvious?

This does not directly answer your question, but it might also be helpful: an alternative proof given in Zariski & Samuel's Commutative Algebra, section 5.2, page 259: By considering quotient rings $B/\mathfrak{q}\supseteq (A+\mathfrak{q})/\mathfrak{q}\cong A/(A\cap\mathfrak{q})=A/\mathfrak{p}$, we may assume $\mathfrak{p}$, $\mathfrak{q}$ are respectively the zero ideal of $A$ and $B$, $A$, $B$ are integral domains (since they both admit $(0)$ as prime ideals), and $\mathfrak{q}'\cap A=(0)$.

We want to prove $\mathfrak{q}'=(0)$. If $\mathfrak{q}'\ni x\ne 0$, say $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=0$ (by the integral dependence hypothesis). If $a_0=0$ then we can divide $x$ since $B$ is an integral domain. Therefore we assume $a_0\ne 0$. Then $a_0\in\mathfrak{q}'$ since $a_0=-(x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x)$ and $x\in\mathfrak{q}'$, and hence $a_0\in \mathfrak{q}'\cap A$, which contradicts $\mathfrak{q}'\cap A=(0)$.

@Asigan Thank you for showing an alternative proof. I will check that proof in Zariski & Samuel’s book.

1, $A_{\mathfrak{p}}=(A-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}A$ and $B_{\mathfrak{p}}=({\color{violet}A}-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}B$.
Hence $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ can be viewed as a subring of $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and the latter is integral over the former.
For convenience set $S=A-\mathfrak{p}$.
2, $\mathfrak{n}$ is the extension of $\mathfrak{q}$ with respect to $B\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$, $b\mapsto \frac b1$.
Then it is not hard for you to check
$$ \mathfrak{n}=\{\frac xs:\, x\in\mathfrak{q},\, s\in S   \}.  $$
3, As for $\mathfrak{n}^c$, the contraction is taken with respect to $A_{\mathfrak{p}}\to B_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the inclusion. Hence actually $\mathfrak{n}^c=\mathfrak{n}\cap A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
4, Finally we check $\mathfrak{n}^c=\mathfrak{m}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{n}\cap A_{\mathfrak{p}}=\mathfrak{m}$.
Assume $\xi\in \mathfrak{n}\cap A_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Since $\xi\in\mathfrak{n}$, we may assume $\xi=\frac xs$, $x\in\mathfrak{q}$, $s\in S$ (see item 2).
Since $\xi=\frac xs\in A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ we have $\frac{x}{s}=\frac{a}{s'}$ with $a\in A$, $s'\in S$,
i.e. $s''s'x=s''sa$ for some $s''\in S$.
$x\in\mathfrak{q}$ implies $s''sa\in\mathfrak{q}$.
Since $ss''\in S=A-\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=A\cap\mathfrak{q}$, therefore $ss''\notin\mathfrak{q}$.
Since $s''sa\in\mathfrak{q}$, therefore $a\in\mathfrak{q}$, i.e. $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ (recall $\mathfrak{p}=A\cap\mathfrak{q}$).
Then $\xi=\frac{a}{s'}\in\mathfrak{m}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{n}^c\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$.
The converse inclusion is immediate.

By maximality of $\mathfrak{m}$, it is suffices to show only converse inclusion, i.e. $$\mathfrak{m}=(\mathfrak{q}\cap A)^e\subseteq \mathfrak{q}^e\cap A_\mathfrak{p}= \mathfrak{n}^c$$ where left hand side of inclusion represent extension in $A\to A_\mathfrak{p}$ and right hand side in $B\to B_\mathfrak{p}$. Clearly  $(\mathfrak{q}\cap A)^e\subseteq A_\mathfrak{p}$. Observe $(\mathfrak{q}\cap A)^e=S^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}\cap A)\subseteq S^{-1} \mathfrak{q}= \mathfrak{q}^e$. Thus $(\mathfrak{q}\cap A)^e\subseteq \mathfrak{q}^e \cap A_\mathfrak{p}$.
